# What kinds of sites should I focus on for a "new look and concept" redesign, and how much of a regular UX process should I follow?

Tags: guidelines, design-process, prototype, redesign

On [Behance](http://www.behance.net/), I've seen many "new look and concept" redesigns such as [this one for Facebook](http://www.behance.net/gallery/Facebook-New-Look-Concept/6504647) and [this one for Wikipedia](http://www.behance.net/gallery/Wikipedia-Redesign/2908767).  The gist of one of these projects is that you ask yourself, "If I could redesign this site/app in any way I could, how would I do it?"  Then you perform the redesign in that manner.

A prospect with a project that I really wanted turned me down about a month ago saying, essentially, that he wanted to do the redesign himself on his own time.  He is a mostly back-end developer rather than a designer - and, for those of you who have read *[Inmates](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Inmates_Are_Running_the_Asylum.html?id=04cFCVXC_AUC)*, hopefully not too much like *Homo logicus* to design something that works for perpetual intermediates!  So I guess the first half of my question is, should I pursue a new look and concept redesign for this kind of site?  Or am I calling his baby ugly if a conceptual redesign from me ever shows up?

The second half of my question: Should I treat a new look and concept redesign as a full UX project where I follow all of my normal processes?  What would you include in one of these projects out of these:

- User interviews
- User surveys
- Card sorting tests
- Personas
- User requirements
- Wireframes
- Medium-/high-fidelity prototypes
- A/B tests
- Usability testing

Should I make the prototypes interactive or just show them as static images?

I'm also concerned about the cost of doing a new look and concept redesign properly, since I wouldn't be paid for a project like this and a lot of the steps here that involve users require a budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key question to ask yourself, as with most things, is: why?

If your goal is to convince this particular prospect to reconsider and let you design his site, I would say don't bother.  He can always reconsider.

In a more general case, ask yourself: why do I want to create a redesign?

- If this is something for your portfolio, you probably want to be thorough, since the point is to demonstrate that you know how to execute this process.
- If this is for a client, you should execute the process to the extent the client needs.  They may just want exploratory ideas to get a feel for if they want to redesign their site, or they may want a carefully-crafted plan of action that they can take under immediate consideration.  You can invest your own effort accordingly.
- If this is to explore a business or design concept for yourself, then you're just your own client.  See above.
- If this is for fun, then obviously you should only invest as much into it as makes it fun for you.